# mysql: use a procedure inside a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, procedures

I need to call a procedure that modifies root password inside a trigger.
This is the procedure

```
delimiter //
create procedure foobar ()
begin SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = 'foobar';
end//
delimiter ;
```

and this is the trigger

```
delimiter //
create trigger rootpass
after delete on map
for each row
begin
call foobar;
end //
delimiter ;
```

It seems the syntax is correct but when I launch a delete I get this error

> ERROR 1445 (HY000): Not allowed to set autocommit from a stored function or trigger

So I think I'm trying to do a forbidden thing, is there any way this could work in mysql?
I know the whole thing sounds weird/horrible but this is the way for my application to understand that something has been deleted.

Comment: It makes **no** sense to modify the root password within a procedure.  Someone, somewhere, has solved entirely the wrong problem.

Comment: Yes, it makes no sense, 100% agree, I'm a fool, and this is a terrible thing to do. Still, I need to know if somehow this is technically possible by some dirty trick, if I ask is because I need to test proof some external code.

Comment: I've answered your question, below, but... *"Still, I need to know if somehow this is technically possible by some dirty trick, if I ask is because I need to test proof some external code."*  ...that statement feels as if you are playing  games, here... we prefer [questions about your actual problem, not questions about your attempted solution](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Ok, my actual problem is that an engine that uses mysql is unable to retrieve query status, I must find a way to signal the app that the query is finished, so one way is to break communication with the db, this signals the app that something has happened. Afterwards I can re-establish the communication and go on. This is why I wanted to change the root psw. Another option is to shutdown the server, or change the port, is this something that can be done through a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing a statement [would cause an implicit commit of the current transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html), that statement is not permitted within a trigger or stored function.

This includes a statement in a stored procedure that is invoked by a trigger or function -- there is no layer of abstraction here that makes the invalid action any more valid.